# How to set default uuid on save model Laravel 5.3+?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model

How I can set my own property on model ***before save it***, but only when I created a new row/entry?

Example PHP:

```
class foo extends controller {
    // ..
    public function create () {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'Jack';
        $user->lastname = 'Smith';
        $user->save();
    }
    // ..
}
```

Model:

```
class User extends Model {
    // ...
    public function beforeSave() {
        $this->token = uuid();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE User
    (
      `uuid` varchar(55),
      `name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
      `lastname` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
      primary key (`uuid`)
    )
;
```

Comment: Perhaps this solution will help you or indicate the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817067/laravel-5-using-a-uuid-as-primary-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as I know inside your model add the method boot()

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function($model){
        // ... code here
    });

}
```

just like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993599/1290292) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38689351/1290292)

or you can use [model observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers)